# Setting height to element with floating elements that can't be cleared

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to make a blog theme in WordPress and I'm encountering an issue with following the structure/classes.

My current markup goes:

```
<div class="container blog-post">
    <div class="row">

        <section>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
                <article>
                    [Blog post content]
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
            <aside>
                [Sidebar content]
            </aside>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

As illustrated, the `<section>` height is only affected by the margin and padding, not the content.

Since Bootstrap's `col-xx-xx` classes are floated left, my section is only accumulating height based on its margin and padding, not the child elements. If I clear the float after the section, then the sidebar doesn't display on the right, like I want it to.

I tried setting the section overflow to hidden and other values, but then the sidebar either cleared to the row below, or the section height didn't change.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: do you want the height of the sidebar to follow the height of the article? i can't understand what you need

Comment: Not the sidebar, just the blog post content (`<article>`). At the moment, if I apply a bottom padding or margin to the `<section>` element, it has no visual effect because it's only about 200px tall. I've updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: why do you need this section tag over there?

Comment: I think I resolved my issue by first replacing the section with main, then, placing the sidebar within main, then, setting main's overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

you have your layout wrong.

you are seeing what you are seeing because you are not applying a clearfix to that section. and if you do (as you noticed already) the sidebar stacks down the post because `<section>` is a block element and takes 100% of width space, therefore pushing the sidebar down the dom.

you should either include the sidebar in the section (and apply a clearfix), or float that section as well like so:

```
section {
overflow:auto;
float:left;
}
```

i suggest including the sidebar in the section, or removing that section tag all togheter

Comment: I'd like to keep the tags I'm using because it means it's semantically correct. The sidebar is already included in the section and floated, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @MarioParra uhm no.. the sidebar is outside the section in your code

Comment: I mis-typed, but it should be outside. It doesn't really make sense for the sidebar to be inside the section, especially on a page with multiple posts, and therefore, sections. Like I said, to keep semantics, I don't really want to get rid of the tag. I guess I could add the clearfix, then set the section's display to inline.

Comment: Adding this fixes the height issue, but then the section takes up 100% of the width, like you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your layout a bit. Bootstrap works fine with row and cols, you just have to make it look something like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="main col-lg-8">
        /* your content */
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar col-lg-4">
        /* your sidebar */
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the improvement? To me, it just looks like removing semantics.

Comment: Please, draw the desired effect, cause I cannot get it quite right from your description

Comment: If you're looking for standard content+sidebar behavior you may use the offered solution